# Switch branches, keep same change-set

Tags: gerrit

I have a change-set in Gerrit that for a while has been based off of the `master` branch.

So, my push commands have looked like this:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

But now, I need to start working off of a topic branch (but still using the same change-set).
So, I tried pushing like this:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/myTopicBranch
```

But, **this seems to have created a whole new change-set**, rather than simply altering the metadata of my current change (as updating a topic does).

Is there a way associate a change-set with a different branch after creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't do that. If you want to work in a different branch, push to this new branch like you have done (git push origin HEAD:refs/for/myTopicBranch) and abandon (using the Gerrit web interface) the original change.